# How to plot two y axes in the same plot, each y axis contains two sets of information, one is geom_col and one is geom_line?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data:

```
yeardesc<-seq(2002,2020,2)

prop1<-c(0.6751152,0.6746591,0.6913932,0.74829,0.7085363,0.7679045,0.8328877,0.7802125,0.7992271,0.8180833)
prop2<-c(0.02150538,0.07438795,0.05994291,0.08120438,0.09961588,0.07418163,0.07314629,0.1220751,0.1073002,0.1470971)
money1<-c(3783.255,4512.181,4237.779,4163.842,4267.878,4708.089,4244.439,4407.01,4193.522,5140.635)
money2<-c(382.9129,643.6798,606.3505,600.3303,713.0684,405.1913,463.76,787.4756,572.8035,1010.126)

data<-data.frame(yeardesc,prop1,prop2,money1,money2)
```

I want to make a plot like this:
[image]

Basically, `prop1` and `prop2` are `geom_line` plots (the blue lines), and `money1` and `money2` are `geom_col` plots (the red bars). I want to have two `y` axes with different scales. How do I do this?

Comment: Doing this is *strongly* discouraged because it creates bad (and at worst actively misleading) data visualisations. However, if the two y-axes are merely different scales of the same information, you can use a [secondary y-axis](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html). ‘ggplot2’ *intentionally* does not support displaying two unrelated y-axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really *have* to do this, then you will need to pivot your data into long format and use a secondary axis:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  pivot_longer(-yeardesc, names_pattern = "(.*)(\\d)", 
               names_to = c(".value", "series")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(yeardesc, prop, color = paste("prop", series)))  +
  geom_col(aes(y = money / 6000, fill = paste("money", series)), 
           position = "dodge", color = NA) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~6000 * .x, labels = scales::dollar,
                                         name = "Money")) +
  scale_color_manual(NULL, values = c("orange2", "deepskyblue4")) +
  scale_fill_manual(NULL, values = c("gold", "lightblue")) +
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Proportion") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

However, secondary y axes are generally discouraged in data visualization, as they are somewhat confusing and arbitrary. There may be better ways to present your data - though it's difficult to make a firm suggestion without context.

Comment: Thank you so much! And thanks for telling me that secondary y axes are discouraged. I didn't know that. Here's the context: Proportion 1 is the proportion of adult children who provided parental transfers, and proportion 2 is the proportion who received parental transfers. Money 1 is the money adult children provided to parents, and money 2 is the money adult children received from parents. I want to show that providing parental transfers is much more common than receiving parental transfers, both proportion and money wise.